# Make stacked proportion bar graph for categorical and numerical data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = data.frame(Age = c(rep(NA, 10), runif(40, 1, 100)), 
                Duration = c(rep(NA, 20), runif(30, 0, 4)), 
                cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA), each = 10), 
                cat2 = rep(c("X", "Y", "Z", NA, "W"), each = 10))
```

Of note, it contains two numerical columns and two categorical columns. Each column has some NA values.

I want to make a stacked bar graph showing proportion of each of the groups in the categorical columns and a colorbar for the numerical columns. The order of the categories does not matter for categorical, except that I would like NA to always be at the top, and numerical should sorted from lowest at the bottom to largest at the top (but NA also at the top here).

Below is a brief sketch of what I was trying to make without much success. For the numerical colorbars, I want to annotate the value rounded to nearest whole number at 5 points on the bar.

[image]

I started by melting the data frame to make it long, but am unsure how to proceed from here.

```
library(reshape) 
df_m = melt(df, id = c())
```

If you could help with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: +1 for including a sketch even when you couldn't make it with code. I see some aesthetic issues occurring: your columns display different types of data on difference scales, but you can only work with one color/fill scale per plot. It won't make sense to have a colorbar that spans ages of 0-100 and durations of 0-4. Similar issue for the categorical columns. You'll probably have better luck doing separate plots and sticking them together discretely with `cowplot` or `patchwork`

Comment: @camille I appreciate the upvote and your response. With my very limited ggplot knowledge, I'm not sure how to do that either. Would it be possible for you to post a solution with this? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a far more complicated problem than you were hoping, and with several steps, so this solution feels slightly hacky. It also might not be exactly what you're looking for, but there's room for adjustment.

What I'm doing first is breaking the numeric columns into intervals, which are factors, making sure the character vectors are factors, and giving every column an explicit factor level of `"NA"`, rather than the value type `NA`. It's a subtle difference (you could call this level it something else), but it lets you put this level at the end of each factor so the `NA` bars will all be placed on top. However, fill scales automatically assign a gray value to `NA`, so you'll have to do this manually. I'm doing this by pulling the ColorBrewer palette "Blues," then placing a gray color alongside it in `scale_fill_manual`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)
df <- data_frame(Age = c(rep(NA, 10), runif(40, 1, 100)), 
                 Duration = c(rep(NA, 20), runif(30, 0, 4)), 
                 cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA), each = 10), 
                 cat2 = rep(c("X", "Y", "Z", NA, "W"), each = 10))

df_breaks <- df %>%
  arrange(Age) %>%
  mutate(Age = cut(Age, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25)),
         Duration = cut(Duration, breaks = seq(0, 4, by = 1))) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>%
  mutate_all(~fct_explicit_na(., na_level = "NA"))

df_breaks
#> # A tibble: 50 x 4
#>    Age     Duration cat   cat2 
#>    <fct>   <fct>    <fct> <fct>
#>  1 (0,25]  (3,4]    NA    W    
#>  2 (0,25]  (1,2]    C     Z    
#>  3 (0,25]  NA       B     Y    
#>  4 (0,25]  (0,1]    C     Z    
#>  5 (0,25]  (1,2]    D     NA   
#>  6 (0,25]  (3,4]    NA    W    
#>  7 (0,25]  (1,2]    NA    W    
#>  8 (25,50] (0,1]    C     Z    
#>  9 (25,50] NA       B     Y    
#> 10 (25,50] (3,4]    D     NA   
#> # ... with 40 more rows

palette <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Blues")
```

To make individual plots for each column, I'm using `purrr::imap` to call a function on each column, making a new data frame with the name of that column and the column itself, counting up the breaks, and making a bar plot. I added a `geom_text` to make labels, which also lets you skip the legends. (Like I said in my comment, the legends will give you trouble since all the scales are different.) I'm also removing the plot margins on the left and right sides, so that you'll be able to place plots right alongside each other, and removing the x-axis title, which would be redundant.

```r
p <- imap(df_breaks, function(col, term) {
  data_frame(term = term, group = col) %>%
    count(term, group) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = term, y = n, fill = fct_rev(group))) +
      geom_col(position = "fill") +
      geom_text(aes(label = fct_rev(group)), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray70", palette)) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "none", plot.margin = margin(10, 0, 10, 0, "pt")) +
      labs(x = NULL)
})
```

That gets you a list of `ggplot` objects. I'm rearranging it into the order you showed.

```r
p <- p[c("Age", "cat", "Duration", "cat2")]
```

Then using `patchwork::wrap_plots`, you can place the list of plots in a row together.

```r
wrap_plots(p, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

There are some redundancies if you want this to look like a single plot, so you can remove the left-side theme elements from plots 2, 3, and 4, then `wrap_plots` again with the original `p$Age`:

```r
p_no_y <- map(p[2:4], function(plot) {
  plot +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
})
wrap_plots(p$Age, p_no_y$cat, p_no_y$Duration, p_no_y$cat2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

The advantage of using `patchwork` over `cowplot` for this is that the `patchwork` functions are aware of the space taken up in each plot by axes, so the columns come out the same width, despite the fact that one plot also has a y-axis. To see what I mean, replace `wrap_plots` with `cowplot::plot_grid`.

So that's already a whole lot! And there's plenty of room to do more:

- You can further adjust margins and other theme elements and x- and y-axes to fit the plots together how you want.
- If you want different color palettes for different columns—e.g. a continuous one like I showed here for the numeric variables but a qualitative one for the categorical variables—you could assign fill scales separately, rather than all the same like I did inside the `imap` function.
- You might want to set break labels that aren't in interval notation, by supplying labels in `cut`.